# Edge issue for ng-hide and ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I build a editable drop-down box, it works well in chrome and Firefox, but it has small issues in edge and IE.

http://plnkr.co/JXvhX8CoBELX3uqeUk1T

1. After search, the input cursor stay on the text.
2. Blink during click

I already add ng-cloak but it not work.

```
<div on-click-outside="vm.editableEnabled = false">
<div ng-hide="vm.editableEnabled" ng-click="vm.editableEnabled = true">
<span ng-show="vm.group.name" class="hight-light">{{vm.group.name}}</span>
<span ng-hide="vm.group.name">select</span>
</div>
<md-autocomplete ng-show="vm.editableEnabled"> 
....
</md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

[image: the input cursor is stay appear after not editable]
[image: blink in edge]

Answer (score 0):

i can try suggest not to use interpolation - so no cloacking required, and add some delay to showing  like

```
ng-bind="vm.group.name"

<span ng-show="vm.group.name" class="hight-light" ng-bind="vm.group.name"></span>
```

instead of

```
{{vm.group.name}}
```

and

```
.ng-hide-add, {
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
}
```

UPDATE:
after some experiment found, that blinks ocur on page refreshes, so it may be css problem (as it may be applied with delay), so this looks not blinking for me:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <span>
      <span>User in &nbsp;</span>
    </span>
    <span on-click-outside="vm.editableEnabled = false">
      <span ng-hide="vm.editableEnabled" ng-click="vm.editableEnabled = true">
        <span ng-switch="vm.group.name">
          <span ng-when="" >select</span>
          <span ng-switch-default class="hight-light" ng-bind="vm.group.name"></span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <md-autocomplete

          ng-show="vm.editableEnabled" 
          md-no-cache 
          md-input-name="search-group" 
          md-selected-item="vm.group" 
          md-search-text="vm.searchText" 
          md-items="group in vm.groups | filter: vm.searchText" 
          md-item-text="group.name" 
          md-min-length="0"
          placeholder="Search Group">
            <md-item-template>
              <span md-highlight-text="vm.searchText" ng-bind = "group.name"></span>
            </md-item-template>
      </md-autocomplete>
    </span>
  </div>
```

replaced some divs by spans, so no multilines

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I try your code but it is still blinking in Edge and IE10, and after switch, the input cursor stay on the text. What the version of Edge and IE10 you use ?